# Copy a file, but don't overwrite, without TOCTTOU issues in Python

Tags: python, race-condition, shutil

I know that if I want to copy a file in Python but not overwrite the destination I can use code like this:

```
if os.path.exists(dest):
    raise Exception("Destination file exists!")
else:
    shutil.copy2(src, dest)
```

But the state of the world could change between the time I call `os.path.exists` and the time I call `copy2`. Is there a more preferred way to copy without overwriting, presumably wherein the copy operation will raise an exception if the destination already exists?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the lower-level [`os.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html?highlight=fdopen#os.open) and then [`os.fdopen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html?highlight=fdopen#os.fdopen) to copy the file:

```
import os
import shutil

# Open the file and raise an exception if it exists
fd = os.open(filename, os.O_CREAT | os.O_EXCL | os.O_WRONLY)

# Copy the file and automatically close files at the end
with os.fdopen(fd) as f:
    with open(src_filename) as sf:
        shutil.copyfileobj(sf, f)
```

Comment: `os.fdopen(fd)` perhaps?

Comment: Using `shutil.copyfileobj(sf, f)` would be preferable to `f.write(sf.read())` as it wouldn't read the entire file into memory

Comment: Thank you both! I made those changes.

Comment: This certainly does it, thanks. Two notes: `filename` is the input filename; and someone who wants to duplicate the behavior of `shutil.copy2` would want to run shutil.copystat at the end (though this was not explicit in the question)

Comment: As a security measure, isn't it important to copy the file mode _before_ copying data into it?  I don't see that in this code.  Even if you do add `shutil.copystat` afterwards as suggested above.  I think you need to set a minimal `mode` argument.

Comment: @sh1 can you be more specific, perhaps even write out the code? Is it just a matter of doing `copystat` immediately before `copyfileobj`?